# OpenModelica on Python and external library using mod=ModelicaSystem

Tags: python, openmodelica

I can run the simulation using below code (Building is external library and RoomM is the model), but I want to use mod=ModelicaSystem....to be able to edit parameters.

```
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
omc.sendExpression("loadModel(Modelica)")
omc.sendExpression("loadFile(\"C:\OpenModelica1.18.1- 
64bit\lib\omlibrary\Buildings-9.1.0\Buildings- 
9.1.0\Buildings\package.mo\")")
omc.sendExpression("loadFile(getInstallationDirectoryPath() + 
\"/share/doc/omc/testmodels/RoomM.mo\")")
omc.sendExpression("instantiateModel(RoomM)")
omc.sendExpression("simulate(RoomM, stopTime=1.0)")
```

...below is the code that fails:

```
mod=ModelicaSystem("C:/OpenModelica1.18.1- 
64bit/share/doc/omc/testmodels/RoomM.mo","RoomM", 
["C:\OpenModelica1.18.1-64bit\lib\omlibrary\Buildings-9.1.0\Buildings- 
9.1.0\Buildings\package.mo"])
```

Notification: Skipped loading package Buildings (9.1.0,default) using
MODELICAPATH C:/OpenModelica1.18.1-64bit/lib/omlibrary (uses-
annotation may be wrong).

Comment: I would recommend to upgrade OpenModelica to the latest release (v1.21.0) and to use the package manager to install Buildings library. Your location of `Buildings-9.1.0\Buildings-9.1.0\Buildings\package.mo` looks not like a default location. That's probably the reason why it's not found in `MODELCIAPATH`.

Comment: Try removing the directory `C:\OpenModelica1.18.1-64bit\lib\omlibrary\Buildings-9.1.0` and reinstalling the buildings library. With the package manager the location should be `%APPDATA%\.openmodelica\libraries\Buildings 9.1.0\package.mo`.

Answer (score 1):

For the following Modelica Model

`NeedBuildings.mo`

```
model NeedBuildings
  extends Buildings.Examples.Tutorial.SpaceCooling.System1
  annotation(uses(Buildings, version="9.1"));
end NeedBuildings;
```

you can initialize a ModelicaSystem with:

```py
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem
mod=ModelicaSystem("NeedBuildings.mo","NeedBuildings", ["Buildings"])
```

The important part is, that the needed libraries are in a default location and can be found by OpenModelica.

---

If your model `RoomM` has a correct `uses` annotation you don't even need to specify what libraries should be loaded, it will be loaded automatically.

So it's enough to call:

```
mod=ModelicaSystem("NeedBuildings.mo","NeedBuildings")
```

From the [OpenModelica User's Guide](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/ompython.html):

> - The first input argument must be a string with the file name of the Modelica code, with Modelica file extension ".mo". If the Modelica file is not in the current directory of Python, then the file path must also be included.
> - The second input argument must be a string with the name of the Modelica model including the namespace if the model is wrapped within a Modelica package.
> - The third input argument (optional) is used to specify the list of dependent libraries or dependent Modelica files.
> - The fourth input argument (optional), is a keyword argument which is used to set the command line options.

Comment: I have a problem using package manger to install Buildings package on version 21. So That's why I manually added the package on version 18.1. The error is:Curl error for URL https://libraries.openmodelica.org/index/v1/index.json: Couldn't resolve host name.....Failed to download package index https://libraries.openmodelica.org/index/v1/index.json to file C:/Users/sophie/AppData/Roaming/.openmodelica/libraries/index.json.....Failed to update the library index. This could be because of bad internet connection.

Comment: also for OPENMODELICALIBRARY environment variable (in version 19-21 ) there is no omc/omlibrary and the standard library is in zip file is the share folder. Do I need to point to Rooming folder C:\Users\sophie\AppData\Roaming\.openmodelica\libraries ?

Comment: If you encounter bugs please open an issue on the GitHub repository of OpenModelica: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica
Maybe you encountered https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/10648